# React Native AsyncStorage: using await and async

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get all keys from my AsyncStorage database and then filter them in another function, can't seem to get it to wait until AsyncStorage has returned the data?

This function returns the keys in an array:

```
DATABASE_getAllCoffeeEntries =  () => {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {})
    .then(keys => {
      AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (error, items) => { 
       return items;
      }).then(items => {
        return items; // array of items is returned
      });
  });
 }
```

and this function is meant to call the function above then wait for the result then filter down the data.

```
somefunc = async () => {
  var items = await DATABASE_getAllCoffeeEntries();
  var someItems = items.filter(function (result, i, item) {
          // do filtering stuff
          return item;
    });

    // do something with filtered items 
}
```

Have tried a lot on here but can't get my head around it... any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: getAllCoffeeEntries should be an async function to be called with await keyword,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually return something from your `DATABASE_getAllCoffeeEntries`

You could do something like this.

1. First we wrap your call inside a promise. Which will `resolve` if we get all the items from `AsyncStorage` or `reject` if there is a problem.
2. Make sure that our calls to `AsyncStorage` are inside a `try/catch`. `await` calls can throw so we need to make sure that we handle any errors.
3. Use `async/await` when getting the items from `AsyncStorage` as this gets ride of the `callbacks` that are trapping the responses from `AsyncStorage`. It also can make your code easier to read

Here is the refactor

```
DATABASE_getAllCoffeeEntries = () => {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
      let items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
      resolve(items)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(new Error('Error getting items from AsyncStorage: ' + error.message))
    }
  });
}
```

Then we can call the function like this, though we will have to wrap it in a `try/catch` as it can throw.

```
somefunc = async () => {
  try {
    var items = await this.DATABASE_getAllCoffeeEntries();
    var someItems = items.filter(function (result, i, item) {
          // do filtering stuff
          return item;
    });
    // do something with filtered items 
  } catch (error) {
    // do something with your error
  }
}
```

Comment: And this is the reason I ask questions on stack, Thanks! this really helps a lot and I like the clean way you call the AsyncStorage DB, so easy to read! Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad that it helped you out. `promises` and `async/await` can be tricky.  This is quite a good article https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Comment: Thanks for the link! will study it thoroughly! the code above works perfectly! once `this.` is added to the called DB function in `somefunc()` (was my mistake)

Comment: Yeah, I missed it too. I just copied your code and added the `try/catch`. I've now fixed it in my answer