# Why should I use await before AsyncStorage.setItem()?

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage, react-native-community

In order to set value in AsyncStorage we use

`await AsyncStorage.setItem();`

but what is the difference if I use

`AsyncStorage.setItem() ; //Not used await`.

I've tried it and value will get set to AsyncStorage.

Is it guarantee that value will get set without `await` all the time ?

I know using `await` will wait till the promise get resolved from the setItem().

At the asyncStorage documentation also they have used await, If it works without `await` then why to use the `await` all the time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586703/react-native-asyncstorage-using-await-and-async looks a valid explaination
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120305/waiting-for-asyncstorage-getitem similar to your question

Comment: Thanks @ShashankMalviya I've gone through it, but "Is it guarantee that value will get set without `await` all the time ?" - this query is still not answered actually.

Comment: The value will set but if you want to wait for your next line of code to use the updated value, You should use async await promises. Thats the only point in making it as promise, So that It ensures that your ```local storage set & get ``` has been executed successfully.